# Error de conexion co ODBC 64BITS en Aplicaciones de 32BITS

Tags: sql-server, oracle-11g, odbc

tengo el siguiente problema.

Servidor con base de datos Oracle 12G Enterprise de 64BITS

Mi equipo con el que quiero conectar o vincular dicho servidor es Windows 10 64 BITS Profesional.
Con Office de 32BITS  y quiero vincular con mi base de datos SqlServer la base de datos Oracle.

Problema:

Realize la configuracion de ODBC probe conexion y la conexion es exitosa.
Vincule el servidor a mi SqlServer, probe conexion y es exitosa.

Pero cuando intento comunicarme con la base de datos ya estableciendo conexion en Access mediante ODBC recibo el siguiente error.

[image: Error Access]

En Sql link server intento ejecutar una consulta sin exito.

Asi ejecuto la consulta:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY([GSDCONEX],'SELECT * FROM GDmaster.TWA')
```

El error:
*Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
The OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "GSDCONEX" reported an error. Access denied.
Msg 7350, Level 16, State 2, Line 4
Cannot get the column information from OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "GSDCONEX".*

Intente configurar ODBC desde "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe" pero el driver de conexion no me aparece, solo es visible desde el de 64BITS.

Alguna sugerencia?

[image: Provider]

Answer (score 0):

En general, no hay problema para conectar aplicaciones de 32 bits a bases de datos de 64 bits. Sin embargo, **el driver ODBC** que utilices **debe ser de la misma arquitectura que la aplicación cliente**, dado que se carga dentro de dicho proceso.

Tienes dos posibles soluciones:

- Instala el controlador ODBC de 32 bits, que utilizará el cliente de base de datos de 32 bits (este no tendrá problema para conectarse a la base de datos de 64 bits).
- Instala Office de 64 bits.

Comment: He instalado el controlador pero me devuelve el error:
Unable to connect
SQLState=S1000
[Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-12541:TNS: no listener
El TNS listener es un archivo condigurable .ora mismo que no tengo en los archivos descargados.
@jachguate

Comment: El _listener_ es un proceso que corre en el servidor de base de datos, dónde también reside su configuración. Asegurate que está bien configurado y que el proceso está ejecutándose. Al no haber listener, no puedes comunicarte ni en 32 ni en 64 bits (si es que hace falta decirlo).

Comment: He configurado el ODBC 32BITS de forma correcta y ahora puedo conectarme con Access hacia esa base de datos, pero en SqlServer quiero vincular esa misma base de datos Oracle y no me aparece el provedor de oracle.
Intente hacerlo con el Provedor ODBC pero no tuve exito, alguna sugerencia?
@jachguate

Comment: Si el SSMS de la imagen de la pregunta está conectado al SQL Server que te interesa, allí se ve el provider OraOLEDB.Oracle

Comment: Asi es, ese driver era el de 64BITS vinculado con la base de datos Oracle probaba conexion era satistactoria pero por ejemplo ejecutaba una consulta hacia el servidor vinculado y me marcaba error que no encontraba la tabla o columna.
Esta es la consulta: "SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY([MY_CONEXION],'SELECT RPTDBA_TW.PLANT FROM RPTDBA.TW')
Ahora vicule el servidor tratando de usar el OLE DB Provider Search pero obtengo el error:
"OLE DB provider "Search.CollatorDSO" for linked server "MY_CONEXION" returned message "Column does not exist.".
Msg 7321, Level 16, State 2, Line 1" @jachguate

Comment: Come comente intente usar el Provedor ODBC pero igual no tento exito,
Con el OLE DB Provider hago prueba de conexion y me dice que es satisfactoria pero la consulta no se ejecuta.
Agregue una imagen con los provedores que me aparecen en el SSMS.
@jachguate

Comment: Al final pude vincular la base de datos Oracle con SqlServer, no se porque el provedor cliente de 64 BITS no me mostraba el provedor de Oracle en los OLE DB Provider, tuve que instalar Oracle 11g Express y solo haci es como me aparecio el provedor pero sin poder ver aun las tablas, para ello use el siguiente enlace tomando los pasos desde "Consultar datos de Excel utilizando el servidor vinculado.
https://www.sqlshack.com/es/como-poder-consultar-los-datos-de-excel-utilizando-servidores-vinculados-a-sql-server/
Espero le sirva a alguien mas.
Gracias @jachguate